# Asp.net Web Form for Local Use

Tags: asp.net, webforms, excel, portability

I am trying to build an Asp.Net Web Form project to use at my job. We work with a lot of excel files and a large task for me and others at my company is combining/comparing/updating data in these excel files. My goal is to build a webpage and use asp.net Fileupload to parse our excel files and in the code-behind format the results for us/along with other reports we might want to save time.

Here is my issue. At our workplace we don't have admin rights, so we can't use IIS. In addition opening the aspx pages with a web browser is giving us this message.

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

---

Is there a way to get a working web form project without iis or admin right? Kinda like a portable apps for your flash drive.

Comment: http://ultidev.com/products/UWS-Cassini-Pro/Default.aspx

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about user privileges and working around security access restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asp.net framework is implemented in such a way that it is not dependant on any particular web server: it can be easily embedded in any web server that uses the .net runtime (and, with a little more work, in just about any web server).

Robert Harvey has already linked to one such server in the comments above. You can also use Microsoft's Cassini, which is a little less advanced, but is likely yo be good enough for your duplication. It can be downloaded from https://code.google.com/p/cassini/